# How to make two left floating divs not overlap?

Tags: html, css

I have a main div, which covers all the site. Inside it I have two divs, both with CSS property float: left. The left div is smaller, has less height than the right one, which overlaps on the left one. Text on the right div is properly rendered untill length of the content is greater than height of the left div, then the text sticks to the left. I tried position: absolute, but it didn't work. I hope the image explains my problem and shows what I want to get instead.[image: desired output]

```css
.left-div {
  margin: 25px;
  float: left;
}

.right-div {
  float: left;
  margin: 25px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div className="main-container">
  <div className="left-div" /> content of left div
</div>
<div className="right-div">
  content of right div
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS code, preferably in a Stack Snippet.

Comment: The code you added doesn't have the issue you described. If I fix the typos in your HTML, the code behaves the way you want it to until the right div becomes to *wide*. Then the entire div ends up below the left div. But the right div becoming tall didn't make it wrap the way it does in your image.

Answer (score 1):

Use Flex layout

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.left-div {
  flex:1
}
.right-div {
  flex:1
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="left-div" > content of left div
</div>
<div class="right-div">
  content of right div
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use float. It will ruin the order of everything. Instead, use display flex for main container. Or if you don't want to use flex, give display inline-block to your divs. That is better than float.

```css
.main-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.left-div {
  margin: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.right-div {
  margin: 0 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="left-div"> content of left div </div>
  <div class="right-div">
    content of right div
  </div>
</div>
```